# Custom Listview filter

Tags: android, listview, filter

I am working on a `search` activity which contains the `city` names like `google` `search`

i.e :1st row xxxx , xxxx , xxxx values and the same in coming rows.
my problem is when i enter a letter on the `EditText` it focus on both xxxx,xxxx
not all the first letter values filter.

I have 1st row -Turkey , Bursa 2-Bursa
but the current filter show the first row when i press B in the search.

**My code**

---

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            ((Filterable) SearchActivity.this.adapter).getFilter()
                    .filter(s);

        }
    });
```

Comment: you need to share the filter code

Comment: what adapter are you using?

Comment: the problem is in your adapter code.

Comment: im using ListAdapter and ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

Comment: what is the problem in my adapter. im loading items from json using hashmap

Comment: you need a custom `android.widget.Filter` implementation

Answer (score 0):

put ((Filterable) SearchActivity.this.adapter).getFilter()
                    .filter(s); code in afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) method.

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            String text = search_edit.getText().toString()
                    .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }
```

Comment: check your filter method

Comment: public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
       list.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
           list.addAll(list1);
        } else {
            for (ContentGallery wp : list1) {
                if (wp.getAlbumName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)||Utils.formateDate(wp.getDateOfCreation()).toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                   list.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }